# Dynamically append text to filenames in Bash

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, bash-scripting, filenames

I have the following `for` loop to individually `sort` all text files inside of a folder (i.e. producing a sorted output file for each).

```
for file in *.txt; 
do
   printf 'Processing %s\n' "$file"
   LC_ALL=C sort -u "$file" > "./${file}_sorted"  
done
```

This is almost perfect, except that it currently outputs files in the format of:

```
originalfile.txt_sorted
```

...whereas I would like it to output files in the format of:

```
originalfile_sorted.txt
```

This is because the `${file}` variable contains the filename including the extension. I'm running Cygwin on top of Windows. I'm not sure how this would behave in a true Linux environment, but in Windows, this shifting of the extension renders the file inaccessible by Windows Explorer.

How can I separate the filename from the extension so that I can add the `_sorted` suffix in between the two, allowing me to easily differentiate the original and sorted versions of the files while still keeping Windows' file extensions intact?

I've been looking at what [might](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash) be [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362920/get-just-the-filename-from-a-path-in-a-bash-script) solutions, but to me these seem more equipped to dealing with more complicated problems. More importantly, with my current `bash` knowledge, they go way over my head, so I'm holding out hope that there's a simpler solution which applies to my humble `for` loop, or else that someone can explain how to apply those solutions to my situation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These solutions you link to are in fact quite good. Some answers may lack explanation, so let's sort it out, add some more maybe.

This line of yours

```
for file in *.txt
```

indicates the extension is known beforehand (note: POSIX-compliant environments are case sensitive, `*.txt` won't match `FOO.TXT`). In such case

```
basename -s .txt "$file"
```

should return the name without the extension (`basename` also removes directory path: `/directory/path/filename` → `filename`; in your case it doesn't matter because `$file` doesn't contain such path). To use the tool in your code, you need command substitution that looks like this in general: `$(some_command)`. Command substitution takes the output of `some_command`, treats it as a string and places it where `$(…)` is. Your particular redirection will be

```
… > "./$(basename -s .txt "$file")_sorted.txt"
#      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the output of basename will replace this
```

Nested quotes are OK here because Bash is smart enough to know the quotes within `$(…)` are paired together.

This can be improved. Note `basename` is a separate executable, not a shell builtin (in Bash run `type basename`, compare to `type cd`). Spawning any extra process is costly, it takes resources and time. Spawning it in a loop usually performs poorly. Therefore you should use whatever the shell offers you to avoid extra processes. In this case the solution is:

```
… > "./${file%.txt}_sorted.txt"
```

The syntax is explained below for a more general case.

---

In case you don't know the extension:

```
… > "./${file%.*}_sorted.${file##*.}"
```

The syntax explained:

- `${file#*.}` – `$file`, but the shortest string matching `*.` is removed from the front;
- `${file##*.}` – `$file`, but the longest string matching `*.` is removed from the front; use it to get just an extension;
- `${file%.*}` – `$file`, but the shortest string matching `.*` is removed from the end; use it to get everything but extension;
- `${file%%.*}` – `$file`, but with the longest string matching `.*` is removed from the end;

Pattern matching is glob-like, not regex. This means `*` is a wildcard for zero or more characters, `?` is a wildcard for exactly one character (we don't need `?` in your case though). When you invoke `ls *.txt` or `for file in *.txt;` you're using the same pattern matching mechanism. A pattern without wildcards is allowed. We have already used `${file%.txt}` where `.txt` is the pattern.

Example:

```
$ file=name.name2.name3.ext
$ echo "${file#*.}"
name2.name3.ext
$ echo "${file##*.}"
ext
$ echo "${file%.*}"
name.name2.name3
$ echo "${file%%.*}"
name
```

But beware:

```
$ file=extensionless
$ echo "${file#*.}"
extensionless
$ echo "${file##*.}"
extensionless
$ echo "${file%.*}"
extensionless
$ echo "${file%%.*}"
extensionless
```

For this reason the following contraption *might* be useful (but it's not, explanation below):

```
${file#${file%.*}}
```

It works by identifying everything but extension (`${file%.*}`), then removes this from the whole string. The results are like this:

```
$ file=name.name2.name3.ext
$ echo "${file#${file%.*}}"
.ext
$ file=extensionless
$ echo "${file#${file%.*}}"

$   # empty output above
```

Note the `.` is included this time. You might get unexpected results if `$file` contained literal `*` or `?`; but Windows (where extensions matter) [doesn't allow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060) these characters in filenames anyway, so you may not care. However `[…]` or `{…}`, if present, may trigger their own pattern matching scheme and break the solution!

Your "improved" redirection would be:

```
… > "./${file%.*}_sorted${file#${file%.*}}"
```

It should support filenames with or without extension, albeit not with square or curly brackets, unfortunately. <strike>Quite a shame.</strike> To fix it you need to double quote the inner variable.

**Really improved redirection:**

```
… > "./${file%.*}_sorted${file#"${file%.*}"}"
```

Double quoting makes `${file%.*}` not act as a pattern! Bash is smart enough to tell inner and outer quotes apart because the inner ones are embedded in the outer `${…}` syntax. **I think this is the right way**.

Another (imperfect) solution, let's analyze it for educational reasons:

```
${file/./_sorted.}
```

It replaces the first `.` with `_sorted.`. It will work fine if you have at most one dot in `$file`. There is a similar syntax `${file//./_sorted.}` that replaces all dots. As far as I know there's no variant to replace the *last* dot only.

Comment: Once again, a brilliant answer, thank you. I'm definitely a long way from understanding all of it, but for now I'm gonna leave that to one side and just read up more on command substitution when I do have the time. One question I do have: you mentioned that `… > "./${file%.txt}_sorted.txt"` "avoids extra processes" - is this because we're using basename in the `$file` variable outside of the `for` loop here: `basename -s .txt "$file"`... or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @Hashim `… > "./${file%.txt}_sorted.txt"` is the only change you need to do to your script (ellipsis `…` just indicates everything you have before `>`, it's *not* an actual character you should place in your script; replace `>` and the rest of the line with `> "./${file%.txt}_sorted.txt"`). It avoids extra processes because now we don't use `basename` *at all*; the whole magic is done by the shell itself thanks to `${file%.txt}` syntax. Side note: sole `basename -s .txt "$file"` just prints something; if you think it alters the variable, you're wrong.

Comment: Ah, so command substitution is being used instead of `basename` rather than alongside it. I see. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Hashim Not quite. This fragment `> "./$(basename -s .txt "$file")_sorted.txt"` uses command substitution, the command is `basename …`. You either use this or `> "./${file%.txt}_sorted.txt"` which doesn't use command substitution. So it's (command substitution + `basename`) *xor* just fancy variable expansion `${file%.txt}` without command substitution.

Comment: @Hashim Or maybe I didn't understand your "instead of `basename`".

Comment: Ah I see. Looks like I'll need to be looking up variable expansion too in that case, haha. In any case, I applied the command substitution/basename method for my `for` loop, and I've also noticed that there's a slight quirk in how it operates...

Comment: If the original filename of the file (not including the extension in that) contains square brackets with even a single (ordinary) character in them, like `[i]`, the filename of the output turns into `originalfile_sortedoriginalfile.txt` - in other words, it appends the original filename to the new filename *again* when it shouldn't. Square brackets containing at least 1 character are the only cause of this; parentheses, braces and single or empty square brackets don't cause this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83190/discussion-between-kamil-maciorowski-and-hashim).

Comment: Thanks for the extra efforts after I brought the square bracket problem to your attention. To clarify now: `file1="./${file%.*}_sorted.${file##*.}"` supports only extensions with one period, so the final solution as a whole shouldn't be used on files that have more than one period in them? I don't have a need to do so, I just want to make sure this is clear as it doesn't seem to be so in the current answer and I want to ensure I don't misuse this loop in the future.

Comment: @Hashim More than one dot is not a problem with this. Zero dots is.

Comment: Ah I understand now, there's so many snippets of code in the answer at this point it's gotten confusing. This is the final piece of code I'm left with: https://pastebin.com/6XvWdcKB. It works perfectly for my current data, but if you don't mind I'd appreciate you looking over it just to catch out anything I might be missing. In particular, I thought it might need an `if` statement to contain everything and break in the event that `[ -f "$file" ]` failed.

Comment: @Hashim I have improved my answer, added relatively simple yet robust solution. Find it where the bold text is (or use [the revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1358024/revisions)).

Comment: To clarify, the logic in the final block of code is simply doing the same as what the "really improved redirection" is doing, so I only use one or the other?

Comment: @Prometheus One or the other, true. I added the "really improved solution" and the last part of the answer became somewhat misleading, inferior and unnecessary; I missed this. Let me just remove it.

Comment: One more question, what purpose does the `./` at the beginning solve? I understand in the shell it usually refers to the current directory but I don't understand the use of it in parameter expansion, although I may have missed where it was explained.

Comment: @Prometheus Sometimes it's good to add `./` because of [this issue](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf3). The best way is to use `for file in ./*.txt` instead of `for file in *.txt`, so the variable itself contains `./` and you don't need to add it later. Still a leading dash (if any) shouldn't break a redirection, so `./` is not really necessary *in this case*. You used `… > "./${file}_sorted"` in the question and I wanted my code to be similar.